# passagem por referência de struct não funciona (Fila dinâmica C)

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, fila, passagem-por-referência

Estou tentando implementar uma Fila dinâmica. Quando eu inicializo o programa (inicio e fim = NULL), e em seguida coloco para enfileirar um valor(função enfileirar) o ponteiro "fim" recebe o novo item da fila, porém o "inicio" não, sendo que na função eu estou pedindo para o "inicio" e o "fim" receberem o novo item da fila.

Segue o código para teste:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct no {
    int dado;
    struct no *prox;
};

void enfileirar(struct no **inicio, struct no *fim, int valor) {
    struct no *novoNo;

    novoNo = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no));

    novoNo->dado = valor;
    novoNo->prox = NULL;

    if (*inicio == NULL) {
        *inicio = novoNo;
    } else {
        *fim->prox = *novoNo;
    }

    *fim = *novoNo; 
}

void mostrarFila(struct no **inicio) {
    struct no *aux;
    aux = inicio;

    printf("Inicio da fila -> \n");
    while(aux == NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", &aux->dado);
        printf("\n");
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
    printf("<- Fim da fila \n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct no *inicio, *fim;
    int resposta, valor;
    bool sair = true;

    while(sair) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("************** MENU **************\n");
        printf("0 - Sair do programa\n");
        printf("1 - Iniciar Fila\n");
        printf("2 - Enfileirar\n");
        printf("3 - Mostrar fila\n");
        printf("**********************************\n");

        scanf("%d", &resposta);

        switch(resposta) {
            case 0:
                sair = false;
                printf("Saindo do programa...\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                inicio = NULL;
                fim = NULL;
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("digite o valor para inserir na fila:\n");
                scanf("%d", &valor);
                enfileirar(&inicio, &fim, valor);
                printf("%d\n", &inicio->dado);
                printf("%d\n", &fim->dado);
                break;
            case 3:
                mostrarFila(&inicio);
                break;
            default:
                sair = false;
                printf("Saindo do programa...\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

São vários problemas no código.

1. Na função `enfileirar()` o parâmetro `fim` deve ser um ponteiro para ponteiro:

   `void enfileirar(struct no **inicio, struct no **fim, int valor) {`
2. E isso obriga a colocar o ponteiro `fim` entre parênteses na atribuição:

   `(*fim)->prox = novoNo;`
3. Na função `mostrarFila()` não há necessidade passar ponteiro para ponteiro já que não haverá alteração na lista

   `void mostrarFila(struct no *inicio) {`
4. E atribuição para `aux` é simples:

   `aux = inicio;`
5. O teste estava errado:

   `while(aux != NULL) {`
6. E você quer imprimir o dado e não o endereço dele:

   `printf("%d\n", aux->dado);`
7. Mesma coisa na função `main()`

   `printf("%d\n", inicio->dado);`
   `printf("%d\n", fim->dado);`
8. E chamada para `mostrarFila()` muda para:

   `mostrarFila(inicio);`

Vários destes problemas foram detectados como warnings na compilação.

Comment: Obrigado resolveu meu problema =) Me falta estudo ainda...